# asp.net MVC4 view switcher, not loading css and scripts?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

We are using the jQuery.Mobile.MVC package to utilize the View Switcher to change from desktop and mobile views.

I am suddenly having an issue:

1. View application in mobile view.
2. Switch to Desktop view
3. No css or script files are loaded
4. Refresh the page, and all is working as desired.

When I view the source I can see that even though I've requested the desktop view the incorrect css and scripts are there from the mobile side.

Anyone else come across this behaviour?

Comment: I've noticed too that when I toggle to desktop view, my <html class="ui-mobile"> remains.... this should be <html> when in desktop view.

Comment: Ok, I have somewhat resolved the issue. I needed ajax enabled for some functionality on the mobile side. The jQuery.MVC package adds $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; It seems that disabling ajax is a requirement for view switcher to work ?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to have ajax enabled globally for the application, but to set the data-ajax="false" on the actual View Switcher link. This loads all css and javascript files as desired.